# Basic search engine - after crawling what's next?

Tags: java, search, web-crawler, search-engine

I've created a simple web crawler using BFS, that given some seed urls and a few keywords crawls the web searching for content with these keywords. I believe the next step is indexing such that the search engine can query it, and I was wondering what's the best way to do this? Some of my biggest concerns were:

Should I store the index in a file or a DB?

Do I store the page found as well as ALL of the outgoing addresses from this page or just the unvisited addresses?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Lucene. It is the standard as far as indexing and search performance. [Check it out here](https://lucene.apache.org/core/). Lucene by default stores index info to disk. You can also [store it in a database as well](http://kalanir.blogspot.com/2008/06/creating-search-index-in-database.html).